# Populate .net framework just like option group in html

Tags: html, vb.net

I kept searching but I couldn't find anything useful .
I was wondering if I can populate a combo box in vb.net like this:

[image: dropdown list using <optgroup> attr]

in html we use "Option group" do we have something like that in vb.net ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No ... sorry

If you want to do something like that I would suggest the treeview control or switch to WPF (where you could add a data template)